# Getting derivative by dividing partial derivatives (in ODE linear stability analysis)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

In short: I'm trying to understand how dividing two partial derivatives gives a "non-partial" derivative.

Let me give the context, since there might be notational peculiarities specific to that domain.

Given the following system of ordinary differential equations:
$$\frac{du}{dt} = f(u,v)$$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = g(u,v)$$

and let $(u_0, v_0)$ be a steady solution: $f(u_0, v_0) = g(u_0, v_0) = 0$.

Murray ([pp. 226-227](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98868)) draws the picture of some possible reaction null clines for $f=0$, $g=0$ at a steady state $(u_0, v_0)$ (see picture below)
and states that at $(u_0, v_0)$, the **"gradient on $g=0$"** fulfils

$$ \frac{dv}{du} \Bigg]_{g=0} = - \frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}} $$.

How does one get this identity? Why is there a negative sign?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the implicit function theorem and implicit differentiation. If $g(u,v)=0$ has a local solution $v=\phi(u)$, then using the chain rule on $g(u,\phi(u))=0$ gives
$$
0=\partial_ug(u,\phi(u))+\partial_vg(u,\phi(u))·\phi'(u)
$$
and solving for $\phi'(0)=\frac{dv}{du}$ gives the cited formula.